Flutter web: Handling Javascript callback from WebView
I'm using flutter_inappwebview 6.0.0 in my Flutter app. It targets Android, iOS and Web. For the Web part, I'm stuck on a problem.
I have a screen on the Web part which embeds a Stripe payment Intent URL in a WebView. I can display and interact with the web page inside my Widget, however, I can't get any JavaScript callbacks from it, such as when I have a JS function call on click of a button. I've done this before on native Android for example, but apparently this isn't supported in flutter_inappwebview for the Web Platform. When I try initialise the Javascript interface, I get this error:
addJavaScriptHandler is not implemented on the current platform

This comes from the addJavaScriptHandler function inside flutter_inappwebview. See here:
  ///**Officially Supported Platforms/Implementations**:
  ///- Android native WebView
  ///- iOS
  ///- MacOS
  ///{@endtemplate}
  void addJavaScriptHandler(
      {required String handlerName,
      required JavaScriptHandlerCallback callback}) {
    throw UnimplementedError(
        'addJavaScriptHandler is not implemented on the current platform');
  }

So if this package doesn't work/isn't supported for Web, and others don't work for web either, such as webview_flutter, then how am I supposed to intercept javascript function calls/callbacks from embedded web pages in Flutter? Are there any other supported packages, or is there a way to natively do it with iframes? I've tried using an iframe and I can get most of it done, but I get an error in the Console saying:
[Violation] Permissions policy violation: payment is not allowed in this document.

I believe this is because I'm running the Stripe Payment intent screen in an iframe, which isn't allowed.
So now I have the problem that:

None of the WebView packages support intercepting JavaScript functions calls on Flutter Web
Stripe doesn't allow loading in an iFrame
The community made flutter_stripe package states that Flutter Web support is "Highly experimental".

So what are my options? Ideally I'd like to get around using the iFrame way, maybe by tricking it into thinking it's not in an iFrame. Am I missing something here, or has nobody ever implemented Stripe in Flutter Web before?
Tbh, I don't have much experience in Flutter. I'm mainly a native Android developer so I'm open to someone telling me I'm wrong. I'll happily paste my code below, and if someone can spot something I'm doing wrong, feel free to correct it.
Oh, and I had to set it to use a sandbox in the iframe as I am trying to keep it inside my web widget. When I don't set the sandbox settings below, I can make the payment but it navigates out of my Web app, so I can't intercept the callbacks anyway!
Thanks
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PaymentPageIframe extends StatefulWidget {
  final String paymentUrl;

  const PaymentPageIframe({super.key, required this.paymentUrl});

  @override
  State<PaymentPageIframe> createState() => _PaymentPageIframeState();
}

class _PaymentPageIframeState extends State<PaymentPageIframe> {
  late IFrameElement _iframeElement;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupIFrame();
    _listenToMessages();
    _registerViewFactory();
  }

  void _setupIFrame() {
    _iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..src = widget.paymentUrl
      ..style.border = 'none'
      ..style.width = '100%'
      ..style.height = '100%'
      ..sandbox!.add('allow-same-origin')
      ..sandbox!.add('allow-scripts')
      ..sandbox!.add('allow-forms')
      ..sandbox!.add('allow-popups')
    ;

    // Set an ID for the iframe element
    _iframeElement.id = 'payment-iframe';
  }

  void _listenToMessages() {
    window.onMessage.listen((event) {
      if (event.data['handler'] == 'navigateToPostPayment') {
        _handleOnboardedMessage(event.data['message']);
      }
    });
  }

  void _registerViewFactory() {
    // Register the view factory only if it has not been registered yet
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'payment-iframe',
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox(height: 800, child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'payment-iframe'));
  }
}

